# Somar dias numa data em EditText

Tags: android

Tenho uma data no formato dd-MM-yyyy em um EditText com InputType="date"chamada "inicio".

Quero pegar esta data, colocar seu conteúdo na variável Date chamada "inifer" e nesta data somar uma variável inteira chamada "diafer" e subtrair 1 e jogar na variável "terfer".

Meus comandos são:

```
    String datastr = inicio.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date inifer = new Date();
    try
    {
        inifer = dateFormat.parse(datastr);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("Data de início", dateFormat.format(inifer));
    int diafer = Integer.parseInt(diasfer.getText().toString());
    Log.i("dias de férias", String.valueOf(diafer));

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date terfer = inifer;
    c.setTime(terfer);
    c.add(c.DATE, diafer - 1);
    terfer.setTime(c.DATE);
    int mester = c.MONTH;
    int diater = c.DAY_OF_MONTH;
    Log.i("mês de término férias", String.valueOf(mester));
    Log.i("dia de término férias", String.valueOf(diater));
```

As Logs mostram o conteúdo correto, exceto os dois últimos.

Com a data de 10/05/2016 e 30 dias de férias, elas mostram o mês 2 e o dia 5, quando deveria ser mês 6 e dia 8, pois 29 dias depois de 10/05/2016 é dia 08/06/2016.

Onde foi que eu errei?

Comment: Mostra data de término 31/12/1969. Alterei para o código e deu o mesmo resultado:

`código´
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date terfer = inifer;
        c.set(c.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia);
        c.set(c.MONTH, mes);
        c.set(c.YEAR, ano);
        c.add(c.DAY_OF_MONTH, diafer - 1);
        terfer.setTime(c.DATE);

        int mester = c.MONTH;
        int diater = c.DAY_OF_MONTH;
        Log.i("Data de término", dateFormat.format(terfer));
        Log.i("mês de término férias", String.valueOf(mester));
        Log.i("dia de término férias", String.valueOf(diater));

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o método `get` de [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) para retornar as informações dos campos desejados.

```
String datastr = inicio.getText().toString();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date inifer = new Date();
try
{
    inifer = dateFormat.parse(datastr);
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("Data de início", dateFormat.format(inifer));
int diafer = Integer.parseInt(diasfer.getText().toString());
Log.i("dias de férias", String.valueOf(diafer));

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Date terfer = inifer;
c.setTime(terfer);
c.add(c.DATE, diafer - 1);
// Não necessário terfer é atualizado por referência
//terfer.setTime(c.DATE);
int mester = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int diater = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
Log.i("mês de término férias", String.valueOf(mester));
Log.i("dia de término férias", String.valueOf(diater));
```

Comment: Obrigado, ficou perfeito